# How to find the dates between two specified date?

Tags: php

If I have two dates 20-4-2010 and 22-4-2010
in two text box and 
I want the dates to be like this 20, 21, 22. How do I get that ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am pretty sure this has been answered a quadrillion times before, but anyway:

```
$start = strtotime('20-04-2010 10:00');
$end   = strtotime('22-04-2010 10:00');
for($current = $start; $current <= $end; $current += 86400) {
    echo date('d-m-Y', $current);
}
```

The `10:00` part is to prevent the code to skip or repeat a day due to daylight saving time.

By giving the number of days:

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 2; $i++) {
    echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime("20-04-2010 +$i days"));
}
```

With PHP5.3

```
$period = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('20-04-2010'),
    DateInterval::createFromDateString('+1 day'),
    new DateTime('23-04-2010') // or pass in just the no of days: 2
);

foreach ( $period as $dt ) {
  echo $dt->format( 'd-m-Y' );
}
```

Comment: +1 for the Date* classes, -1 for calling it "fancy" and "overkill", +1 for giving something other than the oft-quoted `strtotime` solution. :)

Comment: @gordon can you explain why setting the 10:00am time there allows those to account for DST appropriately?  For reference why I ask, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15302469/problems-with-finding-the-days-between-two-unix-timestamps

Comment: @Gordon Aha.  I see, thank you very much, saved me a huge headache =).

Comment: @Shackrock you are welcome. Note that it does not have to be 10:00 specifically. It just should  not be a time that would cause a day change after applying or removing DST.

Comment: @gordon Yea good clarification.  I did a few tests, what I was using in my old code was typically start of the day or the end of the day, so in both cases I was losing a day!

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`mktime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php).

> mktime() is useful for doing date arithmetic and validation, as it will automatically calculate the correct value for out-of-range input.

If you increment the day number you get a valid date back, even if you go past the end of the month:

```
<?php
$day= 25;
$dateEnd = mktime(0,0,0,5,3,2010);
do {
    $dateCur = mktime(0,0,0,4,$day,2010);
    $day++;
    print date( 'd-m-y', $dateCur) .'<br>';
} while ($dateCur < $dateEnd);
```

Output:

```
25-04-10
26-04-10
27-04-10
28-04-10
29-04-10
30-04-10
01-05-10
02-05-10
03-05-10
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
$start = strtotime("2010-04-20"); // get timestamp for start date.
$end = strtotime("2010-04-22");   // get timestamp for end date.

// go from start timestamp to end timestamp adding # of sec in a day.
for($t=$start;$t<=$end;$t+=86400) {
        // get the date for this timestamp.
        $d = getdate($t);

        // print the date.
        echo $d['mday'].'-'.$d['mon'].'-'.$d['year']."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
20-4-2010
21-4-2010
22-4-2010
```

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* Function to list of weeks start and end.
* @param string strDateFrom  (Date From "YYYY-MM-DD")
* @param string strDateTo  (Date To "YYYY-MM-DD")
* @return array weeks
*/
function getWeeksBetweenTowDates($date_from, $date_to) {
    $startweek = $current_week = date("W", strtotime($date_from));
    $endweek = date("W", strtotime($date_to));
    $current_year = date("Y", strtotime($date_from));
    $current_yearweek = date("Y", strtotime($date_from)) . $startweek;
    $end_yearweek = date("Y", strtotime($date_to)) . $endweek;
    $start_day = 0;
    $end_day = 0;
    while ($current_yearweek <= $end_yearweek) {
        $dto = new DateTime();
        if ($start_day == 0) {
        $start_day = $dto->setISODate(date("Y", strtotime($date_from)), $current_week, 0)->format('Y-m-d');
        $end_day = $dto->setISODate(date("Y", strtotime($date_from)), $current_week, 6)->format('Y-m-d');
        } else {
        $start_day = $dto->setISODate(date("Y", strtotime($end_day)), $current_week, 0)->format('Y-m-d');
        $end_day = $dto->setISODate(date("Y", strtotime($end_day)), $current_week, 6)->format('Y-m-d');
        }

        $arr_weeks[sprintf("%02d", $current_week)] = $start_day . " =>" . $end_day;
        $last_yearweek_in_year = $current_year . date("W", strtotime('31-12-' . $current_year));

        if ($current_yearweek == $last_yearweek_in_year) {      //last week in the year
        $current_week = 1;
        $current_year = ($current_year + 1);
        } else {
        $current_week = ($current_week + 1);
        }
        $current_yearweek = $current_year . sprintf("%02d", $current_week);
    }
    return $arr_weeks;
}
```

Run Like : date_from=2015-10-20 , date_to=2016-04-15

```
$arr_weeks = $this->getWeeksBetweenTowDates($date_from, $date_to);
```

Output:

```
    Array
(
    [43] => 2015-10-18 =>2015-10-24
    [44] => 2015-10-25 =>2015-10-31
    [45] => 2015-11-01 =>2015-11-07
    [46] => 2015-11-08 =>2015-11-14
    [47] => 2015-11-15 =>2015-11-21
    [48] => 2015-11-22 =>2015-11-28
    [49] => 2015-11-29 =>2015-12-05
    [50] => 2015-12-06 =>2015-12-12
    [51] => 2015-12-13 =>2015-12-19
    [52] => 2015-12-20 =>2015-12-26
    [53] => 2015-12-27 =>2016-01-02
    [01] => 2016-01-03 =>2016-01-09
    [02] => 2016-01-10 =>2016-01-16
    [03] => 2016-01-17 =>2016-01-23
    [04] => 2016-01-24 =>2016-01-30
    [05] => 2016-01-31 =>2016-02-06
    [06] => 2016-02-07 =>2016-02-13
    [07] => 2016-02-14 =>2016-02-20
    [08] => 2016-02-21 =>2016-02-27
    [09] => 2016-02-28 =>2016-03-05
    [10] => 2016-03-06 =>2016-03-12
    [11] => 2016-03-13 =>2016-03-19
    [12] => 2016-03-20 =>2016-03-26
    [13] => 2016-03-27 =>2016-04-02
    [14] => 2016-04-03 =>2016-04-09
    [15] => 2016-04-10 =>2016-04-16
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, Hope it help helps

```
$begin = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date);
$end = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));
$begin = new DateTime($begin);
$end = new DateTime($end);

for ($i = $begin; $i <= $end; $i=$i->modify('+1 day')) {
    echo $i->format('Y-m-d');
}
```