# Finding days between 2 unix timestamps in php

Tags: php, unix, timestamp, strtotime, mktime

Hay, i have a database holding events. There are 2 fields 'start' and 'end', these contain timestamps. When an admin enters these dates, they only have the ability to set the day,month,year. So we are only dealing with stamps containing days,months,years, not hours,minutes,seconds (hours,minutes and seconds are set to 0,0,0).

I have an event with the start time as 1262304000 and the end time as 1262908800. These convert to Jan 1 2010 and Jan 8 2010. How would i get all the days between these timestamps? I want to be able to return Jan 2 2010 (1262390400), Jan 3 2010 (1262476800) .. all the way to the end stamp. These events could cross over into different months, say May 28 to June 14.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to find the dates between two dates specified](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736784/how-to-find-the-dates-between-two-dates-specified)

Comment: All these solutions adjusting by 86400 will fail when the dates span daylight savings change

Comment: Mark Baker > That's the problem with unix timestamps. Using DateTime class may be more appropriate, although I didn't check if we could do this easily.

Comment: @Vincent - There's an example block of code that does exactly this using datePeriod/dateInterval/dateTime in Gordon's link.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You just have to calculate the number of seconds between the two dates, then divide to get days :

```
$numDays = abs($smallestTimestamp - $biggestTimestamp)/60/60/24;
```

Then, you can use a for loop to retrieve the dates :

```
$numDays = abs($smallestTimestamp - $biggestTimestamp)/60/60/24;

for ($i = 1; $i < $numDays; $i++) {
    echo date('Y m d', strtotime("+{$i} day", $smallestTimestamp)) . '<br />';
}
```

Again, if you don't know which timestamp is the smallest, you can use the min() function (second argument in strtotime).

Comment: Is there a way to modify this so that it doesn't matter which way around they are?

Comment: Yes, use abs() function on the whole thing.

Comment: This would give you how many days there are between the two dates, but not day, month nor year.

Comment: True, but then you can use a for loop and strtotime. I'll just edit my post.

Comment: The `abs` is redundant once you know which is the smaller and which is the bigger timestamp. Rather, I would do `if($small > $big) list($small,$big) = array($big,$small)` to swap them.

Comment: @VincentSavard What about DST?

Comment: I found this to be my solution: intval(($big - $small)/60/60/24)

Answer (score 3):

I think that a quick workaround for this is to subtract the amount of a days worth of seconds from the end_stamp until you get to the start_tag.

```
//1 day = 86400 seconds
```

I would build an array of the days to use later.

EDIT (example)

```
$difference = 86400;
$days = array();
while ( $start_time < $end_time )
{
    $days[] = date('M j Y', $end_time);

    $end_time -= $difference;
}
```

This should cover any time frame even if its over a bunch of months.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
while($date_start <= $date_end) {
    echo date('M d Y', $date_start) . '<br>';
    $date_start = $date_start + 86400;
}
```

Hope this helps !

Answer (score 1):

```
$d1=mktime(22,0,0,1,1,2007);
$d2=mktime(0,0,0,1,2,2007);
echo "Hours difference = ".floor(($d2-$d1)/3600) . "<br>";
echo "Minutes difference = ".floor(($d2-$d1)/60) . "<br>";
echo "Seconds difference = " .($d2-$d1). "<br>";


echo "Month difference = ".floor(($d2-$d1)/2628000) . "<br>";
echo "Days difference = ".floor(($d2-$d1)/86400) . "<br>";
echo "Year difference = ".floor(($d2-$d1)/31536000) . "<br>";
```

http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/date-diff.php

http://www.phpf1.com/tutorial/php-date-difference.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$daysInBetween = range($startTs, $endTs, 86400);
$secondDay = date('M d Y', $daysInBetween[1]);
/*
$thirdDay = date('M d Y', $daysInBetween[2]);
...
*/
```

Note that the `range()` function is inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

```
    **This is a very simple code for find days hours minutes and seconds in php**

    $dbDate = strtotime("".$yourbdDate.""); // Database date
    $endDate = time();    // current time
    $diff = $endDate - $dbDate; /// diffrence

    $days = floor($diff/86400);  ///  number of days 
    $hours = floor(($diff-$days*86400)/(60 * 60));  ////  number of hours
    $min = floor(($diff-($days*86400+$hours*3600))/60);///// numbers of minute


    $second = $diff - ($days*86400+$hours*3600+$min*60); //// secondes

    if($days > 0) echo $days." Days ago";
    elseif($hours > 0) echo $hours." Hours ago";
    elseif($min > 0) echo $min." Minute ago";
    else echo "Just second ago";
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
$day = $start;
while ($day < $end) {
        $day += 86400;
        echo $day.' '.date('Y-m-d', $day).PHP_EOL;
}
```

By the way, 1262304000 is Dec 31, not Jan 1.

Comment: Will return days - 1. You need to use the `<=` operator.

Comment: He said between, so I assumed it was exclusively.

Answer (score 0):

get the difference of two dates and divide it by 86400. abs(($date1 - $date2) / 86400) will produce the needed result