# Display all the week numbers between two dates in PHP

Tags: php

Can anybody tell how to display all the week numbers that are covered between two dates in PHP.The dates may be of different year.

IF i am using start date as "2011-09-16" and end date as "2011-09-21" it will show me week 37 and 38.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: *(reference)* http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php

Comment: This question is marked as a duplicate. I don't think the questions are duplicates since this question focus on week numbers whereas [the other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736784/how-to-find-the-dates-between-two-specified-date) focus on dates within a period.

Answer (score 13):

You could use something like this...

```
$startTime = strtotime('2011-12-12');
$endTime = strtotime('2012-02-01');

$weeks = array();

while ($startTime < $endTime) {  
    $weeks[] = date('W', $startTime); 
    $startTime += strtotime('+1 week', 0);
}

var_dump($weeks);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eMO7Ke).

#### Output

```
array(8) {
  [0]=>
  string(2) "50"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "51"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "52"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "01"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "02"
  [5]=>
  string(2) "03"
  [6]=>
  string(2) "04"
  [7]=>
  string(2) "05"
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Using the new datetime component (PHP >= 5.3.0) you can use a combination of [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php), [`DateInterval`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) and [`DatePeriod`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) to get an iterator over all weeks in the given timespan.

```
$p = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime('2011-12-01'), 
    new DateInterval('P1W'), 
    new DateTime('2012-02-01')
);
foreach ($p as $w) {
    var_dump($w->format('W'));
}

/*
string(2) "48"
string(2) "49"
string(2) "50"
string(2) "51"
string(2) "52"
string(2) "01"
string(2) "02"
string(2) "03"
string(2) "04"
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

use a combo of `date( 'W' )` and `strtotime( '+1 week', $time )` in a loop