# How is the best way to check iteration between two hours?

Tags: php, datetime

I would like check how iteration is between two dates with interval 30 minutes.

I have for example:

```
$one = new DateTime('2012-01-20 06:00');
$two = new DateTime('2012-01-20 17:30');

$first = $one->format('H:i');
$second = $two->format('H:i');
$interval = 30;
```

In this example $iteration = 23, but how can i calculate this?

Comment: you create a `DatePeriod` and use `count` on it. Use SO Search for DatePeriod to learn how.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the dates between two specified date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736784/how-to-find-the-dates-between-two-specified-date)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You divide the amount of minutes between the datetimes with the desired interval.

```
$one = strtotime('2012-01-20 06:00');
$two = strtotime('2012-01-20 17:30');
$interval = 30;

echo round(($two - $one) / ($interval * 60));
```

(I've taken a shortcut and am divided the amount of seconds by amount of seconds in 30 minutes)

> http://codepad.org/yhv0hdWl

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using [Unix time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) which is just the number of seconds since January 1st, 1970.

```
$now = date("U");
// In half an hour:
$future = $now + (30 * 60);
//          (minutes * seconds in a minute)

$diff = $now - $future;

echo ($diff / 60);
// returns 30
```

Comment: Oh sorry I wasn’t aware you knew everything about the project he was working on.

Comment: You probably won't believe this, I know it's probably CNN material and it is so exciting but - he specified the two DateTime objects, and you won't also believe this - DateTime actually takes DST into account! I know, sounds unbelievable, someone actually specifying what they use and then in turn you provide a piece of code that actually doesn't work and uses even worse mechanisms that weren't in the original spec! But hey, it's not like it's your fault, it just took some reading before posting, I know it must be hard to do so.

Comment: You don’t know why he’s using an object, or what purpose it has. Maybe he’s using jQuery and turns out it would be easier to send a Unix epoch, or maybe he just wants to know the difference so he could put them in order, or send it to MySQL. I don’t know, you don’t know. The point is that I made a suggestion, starting with “You might...”. He can decide whether he’s better off or not. Your comment was rude and unnecessary. I have taken time out of my day to make a suggestion, and at least one other person thought it was a good idea. I don’t see your suggestion.

Comment: An adequate solution was posted therefore I don't have to post one. Your solution **isn't good**, and it doesn't matter the time you invested - it is wrong. Your snippet doesn't work and it uses the wrong approach to handling dates. We can argue all day who's rude and who isn't, but the fact remains that using **your** code doesn't solve the problem because the starting point is **wrong**. Also, no one has to guess what's being used for handling dates because - it's posted what's being used - `DateTime` objects. Just read before posting solutions, that's all.

Comment: And that would be a fair comment if you’d not been so rude and blunt. Chill out dude, we’re all here to help people.

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially the same as [Tatu Ulmanen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8941538/911182), but using the DateTime class as you’ve done.

```php
$one = new DateTime('2012-01-20 06:00');
$two = new DateTime('2012-01-20 17:30');

$first = $one->getTimestamp();
$second = $two->getTimestamp();
$interval = 30;

echo round(($second - $first) / ($interval * 60));
```