# Checking a date between two dates bug, clueless

Tags: php

This function returns an array of dates in between two dates.

Now it works completely fine, except for some unknown reason, if I put it the month of November or the month of March as the arguments, I get an array of one day less. The other months work completely fine. I am absolutely clueless.

```
function getListofDatesInRange2($fromDate, $toDate)
{
    $fromDate = str_replace("-","/", $fromDate);
    $toDate = str_replace("-","/", $toDate);

    $dateMonthYearArr = array();
    $fromDateTS = strtotime($fromDate);
    $toDateTS = strtotime($toDate);

    for ($currentDateTS = $fromDateTS; $currentDateTS <= $toDateTS; $currentDateTS += (60 * 60 * 24)) {
        $currentDateStr = date("m-d-Y",$currentDateTS);
        $dateMonthYearArr[] = $currentDateStr;
    }

return $dateMonthYearArr;
}
```

I recoded it, and a while loop solved my issue. (although i have no idea what the issue was in the first place)

```
function getListofDatesInRange2($fromDate, $toDate)
{
$fromDate = str_replace("-","/", $fromDate);
$toDate = str_replace("-","/", $toDate);

$dateMonthYearArr = array();
$fromDateTS = strtotime($fromDate);
$toDateTS = strtotime($toDate);

array_push($dateMonthYearArr, date('m-d-Y', $fromDateTS));
while($fromDateTS < $toDateTS) {
    $fromDateTS += 86400;
    array_push($dateMonthYearArr, date('m-d-Y', $fromDateTS));
}
return $dateMonthYearArr;
```

}

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find the dates between two specified date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736784/how-to-find-the-dates-between-two-specified-date)

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly this is caused by some dolt many years ago who decided that the day should go in between the month and the year, rather than some logical endianness (big-endian in most computing, little-endian in British English).

Instead, put your input dates in the format `YYYY-mm-dd` before putting them through `strtotime`. This will ensure that you always get the right dates out.

To test that this is indeed your problem, try:

```
$fromDateTS = strtotime($fromDate);
echo date("m-d-Y",$fromDateTS);
```

Make sure the date being shown is the same as the date you put in. Chances are, it isn't.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting answer, but unfortunately, the test failed. I did rewrite it however, and now it works fine. Check it out if you're interested. I edited my question