# how to find number of days between current timestamp and login date

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)
>   [How to find number of days between two dates using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2040560/how-to-find-number-of-days-between-two-dates-using-php)
>   [How to find the dates between two specified date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736784/how-to-find-the-dates-between-two-specified-date)

i have three fields in my table

```
 seeker
 name ....current_time.... login_date

second field i have created through timestamp phpmyadmin
type: timestamp
default: current_timestamp
```

when seeker get registered his current_time automatically inserted by timestamp

```
 third field is login_date filed. when user logins then this field is updated 

//login date
$login_date = date("Y-m-d");
echo "login date"."".$login_date;
$qry1 = "update seeker set login_date = '$login_date' where name='$uname'";
$res1=mysql_query($qry1,$con);

now current_date is like 
"2012-04-10 21:58:01"

and login_date is like
"2012-05-02"
```

i want to find number of days between these two dates. i dont know how to subtract these dates because current_date includes time too.. or is there any other way to exclude time from current-date i-e it enters only date not time

Comment: I think I got the wrong link... :D But it's very related :)

Comment: the problem is about the timestamp.. in above mentioned link there are only date not time..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
 $login_date = strtotime(x); // change x with your login date var
 $current_date = strtotime(y); // change y with your current date var
 $datediff = $current_date - $login_date;
 $days = floor($datediff/(60*60*24));
```